# Android Application connecting to an existing database

Tags: android, database

I am working on an android application for my institute. I have to connect my app to the existing database of the college, although there is no API written. When I contacted the administration for help then they only handed me a SQL connection string and told me to write the API myself. I want to focus on the application only. Is there any way I can skip the API writing and still connect to the database easily and quickly??

Comment: SQL database is in SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Depending on the database, you may be able to get a java-based client for it. You wouldn't want to, though. An API limits exposure and reduces the require bandwidth. Google "<name of your database> java client"

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you cannot access database without using API. You can create your own database in `SQLite` but it will be local (offline) database.

One more thing, you can migrate database from one platform to another, but you will need an API to access data.